# Which instances are stopped when I scale my Azure role down?

Tags: azure, cloud, scaling

Suppose I have an Azure role with three instances running. I ask Azure to change the role count to two either by Management Portal or via Management API.

How will Azure decide which role to take down?

Comment: Doesn't this fall into the category of "if you need to ask, you're doing it wrong"? Isn't the whole point that instances can come and go as required?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Sort of. When a role is taken down it should stop and properly finalize its work and so a role taken down unexpectedly leads to losing part of already done work.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Instances fail, and you can deal with failure with idempotent operations and resulting work delays. In the non-fail case though: Say there's a render job executing on each worker instance, and each takes an hour. You get an influx of requests, so you jump from 2 instances to 5. A few hours later, traffic drops, so you spin back to 2. You cannot designate which instances to shut down. Let's say 3 instances are idle, 2 are busily rendering. It's possible 1 or 2 busy instance are shut down, resulting in re-running of the render job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As British Developer mentioned, the Windows Azure Fabric Controller decides which instances to shut down. You cannot control this process. I don't think it is always the last number, because I am not sure whether the fabric controller does not rename the instances after shutting down. So even if it shuts down IN_1, at the end of the process we will still have IN_0 and IN_1, instated of IN_0 and IN_2 for example.

You can use the [RoleEnvironment.Stopping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.stopping.aspx) event to handle the proper stopping (clean shutdown) of your Instance. This event is being raised after the VM was taken out of Load Balancer rotation and before the [OnStop Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstop.aspx) of your RoleEntryPoint class being called.

I am not sure where I noted, but I know that there is a hard time limit in which you have to complete your cleaning, i.e. I think the Instance will be shutdown after 5 minutes of waiting the OnStop or Stopping handler (I can't remember exactly, but the fabrci controller will not wait forever for you to clean up).

Comment: The time limit for the Stopping event was at one time rumored to be about 30 seconds.But that was actually due to a bug that has since been fixed. Last I heard there was no timeframe in which the Stopping event needs to be completed, but I would always caution folks to keep it as brief as possible.

Comment: It's 5 mins of stopping time and then it is forced.  It is not unlimited.

Comment: Adding some clarification since this answer was just linked from another question.  The instance removed when scaling down is always the last one (ie. the one with the highest IN_<x> number).  It is not currently documented and theoretically could change in the future, but there are no plans at this time to change this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It will usually be the last one to be spun up. So you have IN_0 IN_1 and IN_3. I've only ever see IN_3 go down when you remove one so that seems to be the one.

However, this is not documented anywhere by Microsoft so this isn't guaranteed to be the one that goes down... just seems to be in practice.

Comment: Someone internally at Microsoft tested this around the 1.2 SDK timeframe.  It was as you say, the latest (highest #) one 90% of the time or so.  However, there were a few results where it was not.  So, it is only a heuristic.