# Windows Azure auto scaling

Tags: .net, azure, cloud, autoscaling

We are using windows azure auto scaling feature based on the amount of the messages in queue on our project. Let's say we have configured scale up and down time for 10 minutes, but one message in queue could be processed up to 40 minutes. And it is possible that at some point Azure will decide to close machine that still processing message. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to prevent shutdown machine process in case it is busy (processing message)?
2. How Azure decides on which machine should be closed on scale down? Does it use backward sequence of the creation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's absolutely possible that a busy instance will be forcibly stopped and then reclaimed by the environment. You can't do much about that the same way as you can't prevent any of the instance VMs from being rebooted during an OS upgrade. Your application should be designed in such way that it cen reprocess the items that were not processed because the instance which was processing them was reclaimed or restarted for whatever reason.

When a scale down happens the instances with the largest indices are reclaimed. So the instance with index zero is always with you because you can't scale down to zero instances.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9031268/57428) for more information.