# What happens to open sockets when scaling down Azure web app?

Tags: c#, azure, websocket

We have a scenario where we use multiple Web apps in Azure, when scaling up I understand Azure is simply starting more Web processes and as such allows for connections to multiple servers, there's a broadcast system in place for the synchronization. The issue is, what happens to an open socket if we manually or automatically scales down? Say we have 5 servers which each have an open web socket, and we scale down to 1, what will happen to the 4 sockets that were connected to the servers that are being removed?

As a side note, if they stick and keep up until the socket is disconnected to the client, will Azure bill me for that time?

If they don't stick, it's only a matter of making sure the client reconnects properly.

By what I've seen so far, it seems to stick, but that might just be a grace period while it's scaling down so I'd rather be on the sure here with an answer from someone who actually knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after quite a bit of development and testing there's an answer. We're deploying using Kudu so Azure builds and publishes the Web app. The IIS instances that have open Websockets will run it's Application_End cycle and shut down the TCP connection.

As far as i can tell so far, this happens before the new site is spun up and accepts connections. Thus, there is no fear of being billed for additional hours. This also seem to occur for *all* Web apps (sites) *within the plan* when scaling the Web app plan (server farm), no matter if it's up or down.

This might perhaps an inconvenience for our users, but with proper shutdown on the server side and re-connection from the client side it should work out just fine.

Answer (score 1):

From another thread a few years ago it was the newest instance that is removed (most of the time) but I cannot find anything about it waiting for the connections to drop.
[Which instances are stopped when I scale my Azure role down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030706/which-instances-are-stopped-when-i-scale-my-azure-role-down)

There is however a management API that you can access to scale down (delete) specific cloud service roles.

> The Delete Role Instances operation deletes multiple role instances
>   from a deployment in a cloud service.

**POST Request**

```
https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<cloudservice-name>/deployments/<deployment-name>/roleinstances/
```

Using this you can monitor which instances you want to remove and send the delete command programmatically.  That way you could wait for the users to cleanly disconnect from the instance before deleting it.

Reference to the Microsoft API doc for this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn469418.aspx

Comment: It's a workaround that might work I suppose, but this requires us to handle up and down scaling manually, which I'd prefer not to do but rather using auto scale. This is an up vote but perhaps not a definite answer.

Answer (score -1):

There's only one way to find out.. test it. (or ask an Azure engineer, but this might take ages..)

I would assume that it would not scale down a machine if someone is connected. Imagine watching a stream and it randomly stops to connect to another server? I wouldn't think Microsoft would create it to drop connections.

Comment: Your response is valid but I can't with good conscience allow this to be an answer as it doesn't answer the question. I will run my own tests but they'll be arbitrary since it might be corner cases of Azure leaving it for this or that grace period. In the meantime I'll also ask the support.

Answer (score -2):

The first paragraph mentions web roles:

On the Scale page of the Azure Management Portal, you can manually scale your application or you can set parameters to automatically scale it. *You can scale applications that are running Web Roles, Worker Roles, or Virtual Machines.* To scale an application that is running instances of Web Roles or Worker Roles, you add or remove role instances to accommodate the work load.

Web apps or web roles require the use of a VM. This is detailed in the first bullet point listed:

You should consider the following information before you configure scaling for your application:

•You must add Virtual Machines that you create to an availability set to scale an application that uses them. The Virtual Machines that you add can be initially turned on or turned off, but they will be turned on in a scale-up action and turned off in a scale-down action. For more information about Virtual Machines and availability sets, see Manage the Availability of Virtual Machines.

The information that follows the bullet points details the scaling process.

For additional information this link also mentions the use of vm's for web apps. The verbiage below can be found in the section titled Web App Concepts:

Auto Scaling - Web Apps enables you to quickly scale-up or out to handle any incoming customer load. Manually select the number and size of VMs or set up auto-scaling to scale your servers based on load or schedule.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-overview/

Comment: where does it say anything about open sockets when scaling down?